# I have an Errno97 in fabmanager for Superset, how to fix?

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-superset

I have all dependencies installed for Superset but when running fabmanager I get the following error:

> [root@host superset]# /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/bin/fabmanager create-admin --app superset --username admin --email me@home.net --firstname admin --lastname user --password abc123
>
> /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py:30: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.sqlalchemy is deprecated, use flask_sqlalchemy instead.
>
> from flask.ext.sqlalchemy._compat import iteritems, itervalues, xrange, \
>   /opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/**init**.py:30: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.sqlalchemy._compat is deprecated, use flask_sqlalchemy._compat instead.
>
> from flask.ext.sqlalchemy._compat import iteritems, itervalues, xrange, \
>   Was unable to import superset Error: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol

Any suggestions on what "Address family" it's not latching on to or how I can debug it?

**Update :**

I've narrowed this down to an error from socket.py looking for IPV6 which is not setup on my RHEL system by manually testing the import.

```
 File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/test/test_support.py", line 484, in <module>
    IPV6_ENABLED = _is_ipv6_enabled()
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/test/test_support.py", line 474, in _is_ipv6_enabled
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 187, in __init__
    _sock = _realsocket(family, type, proto)
socket.error: [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this was to directly modify the test check located at `/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/test/test_support.py` and set the `IPV6_ENABLED` variable to value of `0`.

This was caused by IPV6 being present on the system but the module was a.) not loaded but present and/or possibly for some other systems b.) loaded but disabled in which case the it should have fallen back to IPV4.

Answer (score 0):

**Try running:**
pip install sqlalchemy==1.2.18

**After this run the fabmanager command.**